# Redis c# unable to leftpush?

Tags: c#, list, redis, servicestack

I have created an asp.net form where users can register, all the information gets written into the Redis db.

I also would like to keep track of the latest 10 registered users so I figured I'd do the following:

-leftpush new user object to newestusers
-trim newestusers(0-9)

However my current listobject is not able to leftpush, only add or push is possible. In both cases the new user gets added on the tail.

This is the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    registreer();
}

protected void registreer()
{
    using (var redisClient = new RedisClient())
    {

        var typedRedis = redisClient.As<User>();

        //Store

        var userValue = new User
        {

            Id = typedRedis.GetNextSequence(),
            Naam = TextBox1.Text,
            Achternaam = TextBox2.Text,
            Emailadres = TextBox3.Text,
            Wachtwoord = TextBox4.Text

        };

        typedRedis.SetEntry("user_" + userValue.Id, userValue);

        var list = typedRedis.Lists["newestUsers"];

        list.Push(userValue);
        list.Trim(0, 9);
    }
}
```

I have tried tricking the trim function by doing trim(1,10) where it would effectively remove the first element, but this only works when the list is already filled.

Am I doing something wrong here in my setup using the list interface???

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IRedisList.Enqueue()` API to Left Push items on the list (i.e. Queue semantics):

```
list.Enqueue(userValue);
```